# How to open a terminal on remote desktop of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, session, xrdp

I installed XRDP on Ubuntu 18.04, and it worked.
But, I cannot open a terminal on remote desktop. If I try to open it, it opened on original computer not remote desktop.

And also if I open some software, such as Chrome browser, It is opened on a session where I opened the software, and it is not possible to use the software simultaneously on another session.

I need to make and use multiple session of remote desktop at the same time.

How do I solve the problem? Please teach me.

**startwm.sh**

```
  #!/bin/sh
# xrdp X session start script (c) 2015, 2017 mirabilos
# published under The MirOS Licence

if test -r /etc/profile; then
        . /etc/profile
fi


if test -r /etc/default/locale; then
        . /etc/default/locale

        test -z "${LANG+x}" || export LANG
        test -z "${LANGUAGE+x}" || export LANGUAGE
        test -z "${LC_ADDRESS+x}" || export LC_ADDRESS
        test -z "${LC_ALL+x}" || export LC_ALL
        test -z "${LC_COLLATE+x}" || export LC_COLLATE
        test -z "${LC_CTYPE+x}" || export LC_CTYPE
        test -z "${LC_IDENTIFICATION+x}" || export LC_IDENTIFICATION
        test -z "${LC_MEASUREMENT+x}" || export LC_MEASUREMENT
        test -z "${LC_MESSAGES+x}" || export LC_MESSAGES
        test -z "${LC_MONETARY+x}" || export LC_MONETARY
        test -z "${LC_NAME+x}" || export LC_NAME
        test -z "${LC_NUMERIC+x}" || export LC_NUMERIC
        test -z "${LC_PAPER+x}" || export LC_PAPER
        test -z "${LC_TELEPHONE+x}" || export LC_TELEPHONE
        test -z "${LC_TIME+x}" || export LC_TIME
        test -z "${LOCPATH+x}" || export LOCPATH
fi

if test -r /etc/profile; then
        . /etc/profile

fi
xfce4-session
mate-session
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your DISPLAY environment variable is set to the original session (e.g. set as DISPLAY=:0), instead of set for your current session. Each session will create its own (virtual) display, and only the one you used when seated at the computer will be displaying on the local monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Remote Desktop Terminal on Ubuntu. Follow these steps:
Boot to the Ubuntu desktop.
Navigate to the down-arrow in the upper-right corner.
The system will display your IP address. Now, yo`u are ready to set up your client.
Close all the dialog boxes. You should now see that Screen Sharing (is) Active.
Check your system’s IP address by entering the following command into a terminal:

You will see the computer name. Below that, enable the field that shows Screen Sharing Off.
A new dialog box will open. In the upper-left corner, switch to Screen Sharing On. Configure the other options as follows:
Check the Allow connections to control the screen checkbox.
Check the Require a password checkbox.
Enter a password up to 8 characters.

Click the Sharing option.
In the upper-right corner of the settings box, switch the settings to turn Sharing On.
Find the screwdriver/wrench icon to open the Settings page.